# Adding of users to dropdown list doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Good evening!
There's a problem with adding a user to dropdown list (ui-grid is used). 
I need to push input name by id into dd list after the "addNewPerson" button is clicked, if there's no such name in the list, or to call "alert", if there is.

Here's a code, responsible for the dd list creation in html:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" style="min-width:300px;">

<ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search by name">{{$select.selected.name}}
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in contacts | filter: {name: $select.search} track by $index">
            <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

Button and input field:

```
<button type="button" id="addPerson" class="button" ng-  click="addNewPerson()">Add New Person</button>

<input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">
```

Array of objects with the "name" field, which needs to be passed into the dd list:

```
    $scope.contacts = [
    {name: "Han Solo"},
    {name: "ThetaSigma"},
    {name: "Ollie Reeder"},
    {name: "Amy McDonald"},
    {name: "PJ Harvey"},
    {name: "Sofie Marceau"},
    {name: "Arthur Zimmermann"},
    {name: "Michelle Dockery"},
    {name: "Xavier Dolan"}
];
```

And, at last, the notorious function:

```
$scope.person = {};

    $scope.addNewPerson = function () {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("name");

    for (var i=0; i <= $scope.contacts.length; i++) {

        if ($scope.contacts[i].name == nameInput.value.toLowerCase()) {
            alert("Error, the name entered already exists");
        }else{
            var obj1 = {name: nameInput.value};
            $scope.contacts.push(obj1);
        }
    }

};
```

I've tried various formations of the function, it either pushes nothing and alerts 10 times, or pushes names correctly, but even already existing ones, or pushes 10 times and alerts 10 times after a single adding.

I'm handicapped. Tried to find similar q/a here, but to no avail.
And sorry for my english, it'snot my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working [codepen](http://codepen.io/o4ohel/pen/zvKmmQ) example.

First Change the html for the input to use scope variable:

```
<input ng-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.addNewPerson = function () {
  for (var i=0; i < $scope.contacts.length; i++) {

    if ($scope.contacts[i].name.toLowerCase() === $scope.name.toLowerCase()) {
        alert("Error, the name entered already exists");
        return;
    }
  }
  $scope.contacts.push({name: $scope.name});
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried as you suggested, but I've got the mistake:
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Scope.$scope.addNewPerson
And it keeps occurring in all further variants of re-writing the function suggested by @Kevin Dreßler.

Comment: Sorry small fix ( "<" instead of "<="). updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You ng-model to bind the new user name:

```
<input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name" ng-model="new_user_name">
```

Then in your js, you have to break out of your forloop :

```
$scope.person = {};

    $scope.addNewPerson = function () {
    var name = $scope.new_user_name || "";

    var match_found = false;
    for (var i=0; i <= $scope.contacts.length; i++) {

        if ($scope.contacts[i].name == name.toLowerCase()) {
            alert("Error, the name entered already exists");
            match_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!match_found) {
            var obj1 = {name: name};
            $scope.contacts.push(obj1);
    }

};
```

Comment: Doesn't your logic make it add a user if that name is found? it should break out of the method (return) not just the loop. (see my answer above)

Comment: sure, whatever OP wants really. I wasn't sure if he/she wanted to do more after that.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your answers, I'll try every one of them and comment later.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are fine, I would just like to add the option to use functional programming style as I love to do it and for me it looks cleaner.

#### View

```
<input ng-model="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name">
```

#### Controller

```
$scope.name = "";
$scope.addNewPerson = function () {
    var contactIndex = $scope.contacts.map(function (contact) {
        return contact.name.toLowerCase();
    }).indexOf($scope.name.toLowerCase());
    if (contactIndex === -1)
        $scope.contacts.push({name: $scope.name});
    else
        console.log("Error, the name entered already exists");
}
```

---

A few notes:

- When working with angular, **never** access DOM in view controllers, use directives instead
- Functional programming style will save you a lot of typing
- Using console.log instead of alerting boosts your productivity by approx. 9000%

Comment: Agreed. But assumed that this code is example code and in larger project OP would be using something like lodash or underscore which would eliminate the need to roll your own function to find if name exists.  Same goes for the alert ... assumed that would just set a scope variable which in turn would show/hide some nice message in the dom.

Comment: You are right about this being just example code, but i think that even in example code you can see dev practices. I haven't written alert a single time in probably the past 5 years. Even if my remarks are not needed by the OP, it could help someone improve their coding. If the OP was to use lodash or underscore, the question would've never been asked, but i certainly agree that at some point of complexity these frameworks should be utilized when possible. In my opinion, it's all about the right level of abstraction for the job to be done.

Comment: @o4hel, @ Kevin Dreßler
Good day, It's me again.
I tried to do the codepen: http://codepen.io/ElaineCarroll/pen/XmZppr to show what the problem is, but it doesn't display the table properly, sorry about that.
You see, there's a problem with all the options suggested: an empty line is added into the dd list.
Also, I tried to fix it this way: http://codepen.io/ElaineCarroll/pen/jbZBqE
In this case it shows: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
I'm really sorry for how the table is displayed, my first codepens.

Comment: You have var `obj1 = {name:$scope.name}; $scope.contacts.push(obj1);` on line 116. Your scope variable is named `$scope.userName`. Do you now see why you would possibly get an empty line?

Comment: @ Kevin Dreßler
*facepalm.jpg
Yes, I see. Thank you very much!